# Why is tsCV appropriate to use with model selection algorithms such as ets/auto.arima?

Tags: r, cross-validation, arima, forecast

In Rob Hyndman's book, Rob describes using tsCV to evaluate the forecast accuracy of models returned by auto.arima and ets.

This is more of a conceptual question, but I looked into the underlying code for tsCV and saw this:

```
   for (i in seq_len(n - 1)) {
        fc <- try(suppressWarnings(forecastfunction(subset(y, 
            start = ifelse(is.null(window), 1L, ifelse(i - window >= 
                0L, i - window + 1L, stop("small window"))), 
            end = i), h = h, ...)), silent = TRUE)
        if (!is.element("try-error", class(fc))) {
            e[i, ] <- y[i + (1:h)] - fc$mean
        }
    }
```

So this means for every iteration in the forecast cross-validation, a new ets/auto.arima will be estimated. In my mind, I'm not seeing how this is evaluating the forecast accuracy of a specific ARIMA or smoothing model, since the model estimated at time (t-1) will be different from the final model select at time t. Can someone explain why this is okay?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue when trying to assess Arima(2,1,0) with tsCV.
In my use case I have some daily data and, on each Thursday I want to forecast the data of the next week.
Which means that I want to train my Arima model only one time per week, which is not possible (afaik, I am still quite new in R...) with the default tsCV behaviour.

Fortunately, tsCV allows you to pass a custom function. In it, I train a new model only if it is Thursday. If it is another day, then I reuse the model computed on the last Thursday.

Maybe you could do something similar to have a "fix" model?